# tensorflow how to pad batched text like pytorch's 'collate_fn'?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, nlp, pytorch

I want to pad a batch of text into same length, generate segment id, mask vector, and then feed them to bert model.
In pytorch, I can use the `collate_fn` like below.

```
def collate_fn(self, batch):
    rows = self.df.iloc[batch] # take a batch of data
    ids, seg_ids = self.get_ids_segs(rows) # process data
    attention_mask = (ids > 0)
    return ids, seg_ids,attention_mask
```

But in tensorflow, the data is pass by a tuple of matrix, thus all the text are padded into the max length 512.

```
# ids.shape = seg_ids = attention_mask = (data_number, max_seq_len) 
xs = (ids, seg_ids, attention_mask)

model.fit(xs,, ys, batch_size=batch_size)
```

I found `tf.data.dataset` has a function [padded_batch](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset?version=stable#padded_batch). But it can only pad one input, what I have is 3 input data, `ids`, `seq_ids`, `attn_mask`.

Comment: Can you give a `tf.data.dataset` example of creating `ids`,`seq_ids`, `attn_mask` ?

Answer (score 0):

Probably using apply or map method of

```
tf.data.Dataset
```

after applying batch method should solve the problem.